# Staistics Box Plot Method, Updating a Box Plot

Tags: statistics, boxplot

In statistics there is a Method called [Box Plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) for visualizing the summary of data. I am interested in updating the result for updating the data.

Suppose I have some data and calculate result now some how data is updated. May be some data added or discarded. Do I now have to calculate the full method from the beginning. Or is there any method that may solve the problem.

Comment: This question is OT here. SO is for programming question. For stats question check: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean, variance can be easily updated. For minimum and maximum you need to keep all data, though, if you want to allow removals - if the largest or smallest data is removed, re-scan to find the now-largest or smallest.

Not much more to say. Just do it.